# How do you retrieve a post by slug name through REST API?

Tags: urls, rest-api

It works for my pages but not for my posts. If I go to `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=page-name` it will retrieve the page correctly. If I go to `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=post-name` it will not retrieve a post in the same way. Can someone tell me how to get a post by slug name? The post does have a category too, but I don't know if it's necessary or how to properly add that to the query. All the documentation I have found refers to the [filter] function which is no longer supported.

Comment: I'm passed http://sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=post-slug, its works

Comment: Try the post slug instead of post name

Comment: I've discovered that there might be an issue with my Paid Memberships Pro plugin. Any posts that is considered restricted content is not able to be called by its slug and returns nothing instead of "Page is restricted, please login."

Answer (score 67):

Posts: `sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=post-slug`

Pages: `sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=page-slug`

Custom post type: `sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/POST_TYPE?slug=post-slug`

Comment: thanksss!!!....

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hardcoding the api root it is safer to get it like that:

```
$api_root = trailingslashit( get_home_url() ) . rest_get_url_prefix();
```

and then

Posts:  `$api_root . '/wp/v2/posts?slug={slug}';`

Pages:  `$api_root . '/wp/v2/pages?slug={slug}';`

Custom post type:  `$api_root . '/wp/v2/{post_type}?slug={slug}';`

**Reference**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_get_url_prefix/